# Connecting to Soap server fails on random servers using PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I need to connect to a Soap API using PHP but It has 'No response' error on some servers randomly. For example I can get response locally (xampp + PHP 7.3.5 + Laravel 5.8) but getting error on my dedicated server.

This is the web service:

> http://moghim24.ir:8080/Moghim24Scripts/Moghim24Services.svc?wsdl

As reference when I'm testing the API with http://wsdlBrowser.com I can access functions and recieve the response but when using http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html the response is empty!

The API is not limited to specific IPs. What else should I check?

**UPDATE:**
Example code:
https://codeshare.io/293y70

Comment: I did a test using SOAPUI an I can get response ( error response because the request missed mandatory data ). 
Can you share your code? Do you have any logs?

Comment: @SergioRinaudo The code added

Answer (score 0):

I did test your code on ubuntu 18.04.1 with php 7.0.33, 7.2.19 and 7.3.6, and is working 100% and very fast.

I advice you to try to debug using [is_soap_fault](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-soap-fault.php) and also with [strace](https://www.tecmint.com/strace-commands-for-troubleshooting-and-debugging-linux/). You should be able to find out what is the problem.

```
strace php myscript.php
```